# Angular2: npm module dependency

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm creating a npm module which has angular2 dependency.

I'm been realizing for a time now that there are three angular packages available to set as dependency and I don't quite figure out what provide each one.

```
"@angular/common": "~2.2.3",
"@angular/compiler": "~2.2.3",
"@angular/core": "~2.2.3",
```

Which package do I need to set as dependency (core?, compiler?, common?).